# What are minimum number of services I need to start to have w working sql server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, service, windows-service

I'm looking to start the very minimum number of services to have a fully working version of SQL Server running that will enable external connections.

I know MSSQLSERVER is required but do I need to start SQLSERVERAGENT, MSSQLServerOLAPService, SQLBrowser and msftesql?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server instance (MSSQLSERVER) is all that you absolutely need.  The other services are required for other things that support the database service.

- SQLSERVERAGENT is your job runner and required if you want to run SQL Agent jobs
- MSSQLServerOLAPServices is Analysis Services
- SQLBrowser is the instance locater and required if you do things like run your instances on non-standard TCP/IP ports
- msftesql is the full-text search service and needs to run if you have that enabled